# How to change label text of the ActiveField?

Tags: yii2, active-form

I have created new Yii2 basic project and want to dig in.

There is a Username field on login page:
[image]

I want to change label 'Username' to a custom one, e.g. 'My superb label'.
I have read the manual:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html

After investigating a little I've got the next result:
[image]

I have changed only template and it has changed the layout:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username', [
    "template" => "<label> My superb label </label>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"
])?>
```

How to change the text of the label in a correct way?
What is best practice?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay, just override attributeLabels in LoginForm.php:

```
/**
 * Returns the attribute labels.
 *
 * See Model class for more details
 *  
 * @return array attribute labels (name => label).
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'Логин',
        'password' => 'Пароль',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 55):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput()->label('My superb label') ?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html#label()-detail

Comment: Personally I'd consider this the correct answer, because the question does not state that label should be changed in all instances. For example, consider a model where one wishes to alter the label in _form, because a drop-down is being used for a related table value, whilst the remote ID is displayed in other scenarios.

Answer (score 24):

there is an another cool way.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['class'=>'field-class'])->label('Your Label',['class'=>'label-class']) ?>
```

Comment: really helped this

Comment: You are a rock star! attributeLabels was not an option here for me as I had multiple route/templates on single model.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add such function to model:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'My Login',
        'password' => 'My Pasword',
        'rememberMe' => 'Remember Me, please',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the lable from modles like this

```
'symptomsBefore' => Yii::t('app', 'Has The Patient Suffered from the same or similar symptoms before'),
```

Comment: This could easily be a comment try to give meaningful answer with an explanation to support your answer. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)